# How to get the value of random id using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the text value of dropdown selected.
But my id change after each refreshing page. 
I would like to know how can I get the text value of an id who is changing after each refresh, using jQuery.

### Exemple :

> **First REFRESH =>**   id = "select2-account-t4-container"
>
> **Second REFRESH =>**  id = "select2-account-g8-container"

And so on...

Comment: You need to rely on a selector which is not changing all the time.

Comment: What control do you have over the HTML?  Specifically the surrounding HTML.  Is it inside a `<form>`?  is it the only dropdown on the page?  The only one in the form? the only one in a div with class x ?  If you didn't have an `id` at all, how you would tell us which one you wanted?  eg "the third one inside div id='a'" ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the start with selector `^=` like :

```
$('[id^="select2-account"] option:selected').val(); //value
//Or
$('[id^="select2-account"] option:selected').text(); Text
```

This way you will always focusing on the fixed static part in your `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you may get html tag select by Id or in other way, you no need to use id inside them. Enough apply $(el).val() and get selected value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var el = $('#select_el');
        //value after page rendering
        console.log(el.val());
        //value after select event
        el.change(function(){
            console.log(el.val());
        });
    });
```